# String matching over a 2-D Lattice

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to look over a n by m Array of characters and given an input string of length n + m - 1, I need to check for the maximum number of characters that match given the fact that we can only ever go down or right at any step (a monotonic lattice path).

This seems to me to be a dynamic programming problem where I look at the current optimal solution and see whether down or right matches and makes it better and compare it to some previously calculated value (this is where I'm struggling).  Any insight would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an auxiliary array of *n x m*, on each cell you store the maximum *"match"* you are able to get up to that point. So, to calculate the value of position *(i,j)*, you use `m = MAX([i,j-1]; [i-1,j])` because these are the two possible directions from which you could come. Finally, you write *(m+1)* or *m* depending on whether or not the *(i,j)* cell in the input matrix matches the *i+ j -1* character of the input string.

You can fill the auxiliary matrix from left to right and top to down. The overall result will be of course in the cell *(n,m)*. To be able to reconstruct the path that leads to this maximum, you also have to store on each cell, the cell from which you get your maximum *m* (top or left).

Comment: Hey I just implemented it using this as the basis and it worked great thanks! For some implementation things the indexing was a bit odd but that always takes a bit of debugging.